# duplicate coming in next line of pdf document using itextsharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The image below displays the duplicate data on next page which needs to be deleted. This bug occurred after using `table.splitlate = false;`.

[image: Duplicated data]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show your code?

Comment: Please post the code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: below is the original code....please help...i am stuck here.....(using wrappertable code mentioned below helps to remove duplicate for that particular instance but then it duplicates the whole data numerous times and it completely messed up the pdf formatting.)

Comment: this issue is resolved by upgrading itextsharp.dll to latest version (5.5.13)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using PdfSharp and ItextSharp.

For simple things you need to write a lot of code and it should be encapsulated making your life easier.

I suggest using the  [IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com/docs/)  library which has good documentation and much easier to use.